# Mapping field codes to Strings in a TSQL query

Tags: sql-server, jasper-reports

I have a simple TSQL query:

```
SELECT dbo.tblHospEpisode.PATNT_PASID, [Pat_Given]+' '+[Pat_Family] AS Name, dbo.tblPhysiology.Pregnant, dbo.tblCritCareAdmit.CCDateAdmit, dbo.tblCritCareAdmit.CCDateDis, dbo.tblCritCareAdmit.CCOutcome 
From dbo.tblPhysiology, dbo.tblCritCareAdmit, dbo.tblHospEpisode,  dbo.tblDemographic
WHERE dbo.tblPhysiology.CC_ID=dbo.tblCritCareAdmit.CC_ID
AND dbo.tblCritCareAdmit.HSPEP_ID = dbo.tblHospEpisode.HSPEP_ID
AND dbo.tblHospEpisode.PATNT_PASID = dbo.tblDemographic.PATNT_PASID
AND dbo.tblPhysiology.Pregnant != 2
```

The issue is than some of the fields return numbers that need to be mapped to Strings (there is no mapping in the database.  For example Pregnancy code 1 = "Currently pregnant".  I would like the query to return the String rather than a code. I am not sure how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a case statement:

```
SELECT he.PATNT_PASID, [Pat_Given]+' '+[Pat_Family] AS Name,
       p.Pregnant, cca.CCDateAdmit, cca.CCDateDis, cca.CCOutcome,
       (case when p.Pregnant = 1 then 'Currently Pregnant'
             . . . 
             else '???'
        end) as PregString
From dbo.tblPhysiology p
     dbo.tblCritCareAdmit cca
     on p.CC_ID = cca.CC_ID join
     dbo.tblHospEpisode he
     on cca.HSPEP_ID = he.HSPEP_ID join
     dbo.tblDemographic d
     on he.PATNT_PASID = d.PATNT_PASID
WHERE p.Pregnant <> 2;
```

I also used table aliases for your query to simplify the query and changed the `join` to use explicit joins with the `on` clause.

Comment: Thank you for this.  Just a question - is the use of 'join' stylistic or is there a performance / functional benefit?

Comment: @bugy . . . Apart from being the preferred syntax for decades, `join` allows you to express outer joins, which can't be done with the `where` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) expression as follows:

```
select 
    case code
        when 1 then 'Currently pregnant'
        when 2 then 'Not Pregnant'
        when 3 then 'Gave Birth'
    end CodeDescription
from
    YourTable
```